# How do I make my dotnet core application use different packages?

Tags: linux, macos, .net-core

I am playing around with Compat.System.Drawing which has different packages for different operating systems

Windows: [CoreCompat.System.Drawing.dll](https://github.com/CoreCompat/CoreCompat)
OSX: [runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.osx.10.10-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing)
Linux: [runtime.linux-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.linux-x64.CoreCompat.System.Drawing/1.0.0-beta009)

What is the procedure for making my application call the same API method in respective package in respective OS?

Answer (score 0):

The packages starting with `runtime.` are brought in automatically, the tooling should restore these automatically if needed. (In the case of recent CoreCompat.System.Drawing builds however, I think the runtime package became obsolete)